# How to get kendo listview data item count

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a kendo listview that is bound to a datasource.  When the user clicks an Add button I call `$("#arealistview").data("kendoMobileListView").prepend([newItem])`, which adds a new item to the beginning of the list.

How can I get a count of the items in the listview?

Answer (score 6):

The [total](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-total) method of the data source should return that:

```
var total = $("#arealistview").data("kendoMobileListView").dataSource.total();
```

Or you can get the length of the array returned by the [data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-data) method:

```
var data = $("#arealistview").data("kendoMobileListView").dataSource.data();
var total = data.length;
```

Comment: If I use your suggestion then i can get the count of the items in the datasource but that won't include any new items i have added locally using .prepend().

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do

`var numItems=$("#arealistview").data("kendoMobileListView").length;`

You can always refer here http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview and if that still yields nothing, I would suggest getting in touch with Kendo reps, they're pretty helpful people.

Comment: I have tried that and i get "undefined".  I found the "non kendo way" of doing it like this $("#arealistview").children("li").length, but i would prefer the kendo way.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I think i figured it out: 
var numItems=$("#arealistview").data("kendoMobileListView").element.children().length;

Comment: Oh ok. Based on the API, I assumed the data field was an array so .length could be referenced easily. I guess not. Good job on figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/dragdrop">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <h4>Treeview One</h4>
                <div id="treeview-left"></div>
            </div>
          
      <script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
            #= item.text # <span class='item-count'></span>
        </script>
  
            <script>
                $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
                   template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
                  
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Furniture", expanded: true, items: [
                            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                            { text: "Sofas" },
                            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                        ] },
                        { text: "Decor", items: [
                            { text: "Bed Linen" },
                            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                            { text: "Carpets" }
                        ] }
                    ],
                   dataBound: function(e) {
                     
                var item = this.dataItem(e.node);
                var children = item && item.children ? item.children.data().length : undefined; 
                var text = children ? ("(" + children + ")") : "";
                $(e.node).find(">div .item-count").text(text);
              }
                });

                $("#treeview-right").kendoTreeView({
                    dragAndDrop: true,
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Storage", expanded: true, items: [
                            { text: "Wall Shelving" },
                            { text: "Floor Shelving" },
                            { text: "Kids Storage" }
                        ]
                        },
                        { text: "Lights", items: [
                            { text: "Ceiling" },
                            { text: "Table" },
                            { text: "Floor" }
                        ]
                        }
                    ]
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                #treeview-left,
                #treeview-right
                {
                    overflow: visible;
                }
            </style>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**This is for tree view**